# Composer cannot find composer.json file?

Tags: laravel, composer-php

[image]Last week my composer worked fine. However, today I was trying to update the packages using "composer update"after I updated my code by using "git pull".

My OS is windows 10. The project is built by Laravel framework. Both composer install and composer update gave me the same error. I have tried reinstall composer, it does not help. I also tried to delete the file and create new one with same content.

It gave me an error
"composer could not find a composer.json file in C:\Users\jeff\desktop\work\project. To initizalize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ getting startedd section"
But I'm pretty sure I have composer.json file inside the project folder.

Comment: You're pretty sure your composer.json file is there, or ARE you sure its there? It should be visible right in the folder, or with a `dir` or `ls` in cmd

Comment: @Patrick I uploaded a screenshot

Comment: @CHARITRASHRESTHA I have tried all the solution in that question. It didn't solve my problem